# PTIJ: Why do minor children celebrate Purim only during leap years?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Only during leap years do we have פורים קטן - Purim for minors (i.e. boys / girls below Bar / Bat Mitzvah age.) I thought that Purim was geared for children of all ages and they should celebrate it every year. But, apparently, minors celebrate Purim only on leap years. Why is that?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** In the Megillah it says: נקהלו היהודים בעריהם.   This is a רמז that the the חיוב of getting drunk on Purim holds for every man, woman, and child just like for הקהל. As it says:  הקהל את־העם האנשים והנשים והטף וגרך אשר בשעריך.

**2.** The חיוב of Purim actually happens not only once a year, but every twelve months.   We learn this from a baraita in בכורות:

> ת"ר עד כמה מקבלין אותו בית שמאי אומרים למשקין שלשים יום לכסות שנים עשר
>   חודש

Translation:

> You need to drink for 30 days to cover 12 months [*obviously Beit Shammai is machmir with regards to the length of the drinking*].

**3.** All this is fine for a regular year, but when you have a leap year, there are 13 months between one Adar to the next.

**4.** For leap years, our sages wisely ordained that fasting on Yom Kippur ([כ - פורים] -- Yom Kippur is "like" purim).

> "All who fast on the seventh are considered to have gotten drunk on the seventh AND the twelveth."

**5.** However, minors are prohibited from fasting on Yom Kippur, and so to make sure they are able to be מקיים the miztva, we celebrate פורים קטן exactly twelve months after the previous Purim.

---

Remember that Hashem considers anyone who gets drunk on Purim as great as Tzaddikim who stay drunk all year round.   Lechaim!!